# Facebook XMPP IM name from resource

Tags: c#, facebook, client, facebook-chat, agsxmpp

I'm using FB XMPP and I'd like to know what client is user using. If I use Google Talk chat I can get/set it in Resource atribut. But in FB chat it isn't working. It's allways empty, though I set it.

jid = [ node "@" ] domain [ "/" resource ]

Using agsXMPP:

Set: `xmppClient.Resource = "::ISIM::";`

Get: `presence.From.Resource`

Google: id@gmail.com/::ISIM::478f568d

Facebook: id@chat.facebook.com/

How can I get, that user is using mine client? Has anybody some experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

you should use service discovery or client version for this.
See:
[XEP-0030: Service Discovery](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html)
[XEP-0092: Software Version](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0092.html)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I'm new in this. So I don't know what exactly should I look for.

Answer (score 0):

Service Discovery and Software Version doesn't work with Facebook's XMPP servers. Here's an exemple, I've just tried sending a simple :

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="get" to="xxxxxxx@chat.facebook.com" 
id="5"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>
```

and this is what facebook answers :

```
<iq from="xxxx@chat.facebook.com" to="xxxxxx@chat.facebook.com/xxxxxx" type="error" xml:lang="en" 
id="5"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/><error code="503" 
type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-
stanzas"/></error></iq>
```